# Mysql Update Sum Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, sql-update

I'm having trouble updating the query with Sum. I have two tables campaigns and donations. I want to update the total sum of each donation from a particular campaign

tb_campaign

1. id
2. name
3. total_donations

tb_donations

1. id
2. amount_donated
3. campaign_id

my current query is not working

```
UPDATE
    tb_campaign AS campaigns
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            sum(amount_donated) AS amount_donated
        FROM
            tb_donations
        GROUP BY
            campaign_id
    ) AS donations ON
        donations.campaign_id = campaigns.id
SET
    campaigns.total_donations = donations.amount_donated;
```

And I am receiving errors with my query

Comment: Please add the error(s).

Comment: You aren't selecting campaign_id in the join sub query

Comment: sql error unknown column donations.campaign_id in group statement

Comment: See my second comment.

Comment: i edited my code. but still having error. this time "column total_donations cannot be null"

Comment: In that case you need to publish your full table definitions and sample data.BTW the fixed update won't cause this error.

Comment: I cannot get my head around the logic of using a LEFT JOIN in an UPDATE query. (except with a `WHERE somethiing IS NULL clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If column in `tb_campaign.total_donations` to be updated based on matched record try the below update query.

```
UPDATE tb_campaign AS campaigns
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        campaign_id, SUM(amount_donated) AS amount_donated
    FROM
        tb_donations
    GROUP BY campaign_id) AS donations ON donations.campaign_id = campaigns.id 
SET 
    campaigns.total_donations = donations.amount_donated;
```

If you need to update all the column in tb_campaign table which doesn't matches in total_donations, try this,
**Note:** *"column total_donations cannot be null"* added coalesce to avoid null

```
UPDATE tb_campaign AS campaigns
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        campaign_id,
            COALESCE(SUM(amount_donated), 0) AS amount_donated
    FROM
        tb_donations
    GROUP BY campaign_id) AS donations ON donations.campaign_id = campaigns.id 
SET 
    campaigns.total_donations = donations.amount_donated;
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed  campaign_id in subquery so your join can't work because there is not a  donations.campaign_id

```
UPDATE  tb_campaign AS campaigns
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  campaign_id, sum(amount_donated) AS amount_donated
        FROM  tb_donations
        GROUP BY     campaign_id
    ) AS donations ON  donations.campaign_id = campaigns.id
SET    campaigns.total_donations = donations.amount_donated;
```

but due the fact you are  lokking for mathcing rows  only  your join condition should bea inner join

```
UPDATE  tb_campaign AS campaigns
INNER  JOIN (
        SELECT  campaign_id, sum(amount_donated) AS amount_donated
        FROM  tb_donations
        GROUP BY     campaign_id
    ) AS donations ON  donations.campaign_id = campaigns.id
SET    campaigns.total_donations = donations.amount_donated;
```